# Payload values not setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, payload

I really do not know how to accurately present the issue I am facing but I'd really appreciate anyone who can guide me and I will be willing to provide more details if there needs to be clarity.

So first of all, I need to send a payload to an API and this is how the request should look like:

[image]

Next, I am setting the request to a `usestate` hook like this to be able to handle all the parameters that needs to be sent:

```
const [foodTemplateDetails, setFoodTemplateDetails] = useState({
 menu: '',
 description: '',
 foodOrderDetails: [
      {
        dailyOrder: [
          {
            day: new Date().toISOString(),
            mealTime: '',
            foodDetails: {
              foodId,
              sideDishId,
              extraId,
              extraServings: true,
            },
            kitchenId
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    isActive: true,
    subscriptionDuration: '',
});
```

I made sure to set the parameters like `foodId` and `sideDishId` to values that are already available and these can be seen in the image below where console is outputting the values of these parameters:

[image]

but when I call the endpoint I get a 400 error like this:

[image]

and those parameters that I have set and could view their values in the console are sending as an empty string instead:

[image]

I hope I was able to make some sense in explaining my issue. I have no idea what could be causing these and I really hope for someone to help me out.

Comment: Add a console.log (or better, a breakpoint) to the place where you are calling your endpoint, and check the values of these variables. It feels that you are setting the variables values AFTER calling the endpoint, not before, so they are not initialized to the values that you want. We don't see the code logic where you are calling the endpoint so please, read this as right now we only can imagine what you are doing and why it is failing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

My answer below is totally incorrect, but after the comments I've learned something new today (thanks @JorgeFuentesGonzález), so I decided to keep it. The real problem with your OP is something else indeed.

---

Your JSON body has invalid syntax:

```
foodDetails: {
          foodId,
          sideDishId,
          extraId,
          extraServings: true,
        },
        kitchenId
```

---

Try this:

```
const [foodTemplateDetails, setFoodTemplateDetails] = useState({
 menu: "",
 description: "",
 foodOrderDetails: [
      {
        dailyOrder: [
          {
            day: new Date().toISOString(),
            mealTime: "",
            foodDetails: {
              foodId: foodId,
              sideDishId: sideDishId,
              extraId: extraId,
              extraServings: true,
            },
            kitchenId: kitchenId
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    isActive: true,
    subscriptionDuration: "",
});
```

All single quotes (like `''`) should be double quotes (i.e. `""`).

Comment: [That's valid syntax for object declarations in modern JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), and using single or double quotes do not make any difference and this is not JSON, but a JavaScript object that later is stringified to JSON using JSON.stringify().

Comment: You're right on your 2 last sentences, but wrong on first: on his javascript object, `foodDetails` is an object, and some members like `foodId` are used like they were array members. So it has incorrect syntax.

Comment: Man, read the link I've posted in the comment. Is valid JavaScript to define an object. `{ foodId }` is the same as `{ foodId: foodId }`. Again, just read the link and test it yourself. That's why the typical `export { MyClass }` works.

Comment: Indeed! Sorry for the noise!